# Can SSH out, but not in to a docker container: network unreachable

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, docker, container

Real docker noob here, trying to get an ubuntu container that can be accessed via SSH.

I'm using an image using [this dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) and building & running it with "docker build -t sshable ~/PATH/" and "docker run --name test -t sshable".  I can ssh out to the host and a VM on it just fine as well as other containers running the same image.  However, when I try to "ssh IP_ADDR" from the host where IP_ADDR is the IP address given as "inet addr" in eth0 for the container (when using ifconfig) it can't, saying "ssh: connect to host IP_ADDR port 22: Network is unreachable."  I can also ping out from the containers, but not into them as it times out.  Is the host not on the bridge network and if so how do I get it on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the inbound port (22) to the container from the host to connect via ssh:

```
docker run -it -P 22:22 --name test sshable
```

There are easier and better way to gain access into a container though:

```
docker run -it --name test sshable /bin/bash
```

If the container is running you can connect to it via:

```
docker exec -it test /bin/bash
```